# Why can't my selector read `state`? state is not defined

Tags: javascript, redux, state

I'm finalising a really simple Redux application that picks up a quote stored in the Redux store and renders it on the screen. Struggling to get the selectors to read state (Cannot read property `quoteText` of undefined)

Tried moving the definition of state (`const state = store.getState();`
) around (wondering if this had to do with JS execution order but no success)

```
const getRandomQuote = () => {
const quotes = [
    {
        quoteText:"XXXXXX",
        quoteAuthor:"YYYY",
    },
    {
        quoteText:"AAAA",
        quoteAuthor:"BBBB",
    }
];
  return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
};

const defaultQuote = getRandomQuote();

const NEW_QUOTE = 'NEW_QUOTE';

const newQuoteActionCreator = () => {
  let quoteObject = getRandomQuote();
  return {
    type: NEW_QUOTE,
    payload: quoteObject
  };
};

const getNextQuoteReducer = (state = defaultQuote, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEW_QUOTE:
       return {
         ...state,
         data: action.payload
       };
    default:
       return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(getNextQuoteReducer);
const state = store.getState();

const newQuoteButton = document.getElementById('new-quote');
const quoteTextContent = document.getElementById('text');

store.subscribe((state) => {
  quoteTextContent.innerHTML = state.data.quoteText;
});

newQuoteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {store.dispatch(newQuoteActionCreator());
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  quoteTextContent.innerHTML = state.quoteText;
});
```

Was expecting to be able to define the store listener (store.subscribe) as a Redux selector function (receiving `state` as argument or being able to read the global state variable), but no luck. I always get errors pointing to `state` being not defined.

Pointers welcome.

Comment: Store listeners don't get the state, they need to get the state from the store. https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener You say you did that, but without actually seeing the code that didn't work, who knows what you were actually doing. The `state` you *currently* have will get the state *at that point in time*.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I think you could go ahead and post that as an answer (with a small snippet of what `store.subscribe` expects)

Comment: @vivalldi So... much... effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `store.subscribe()` does *not* pass the current state as an argument to subscribers (see the [API docs for `store.subscribe` for details](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener)).  So, you can't use a selector function as a subscriber callback.  (Also, since a selector by definition just "selects" and *returns* a value, but doesn't do anything else with it, using a selector as a subscriber callback would be pointless anyway.)

Instead, a subscriber callback must call `store.getState()` inside the callback to retrieve the latest state.  You might then call `someSelector(state)` to retrieve the value you care about.

Please see my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) for a further explanation of how Redux UI layers like React-Redux handle the subscription and state extraction aspects.

Comment: Thanks. And great post!